# What is different functions: `malloc()` and `kmalloc()`?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, posix

What is different functions: `malloc()` and `kmalloc()`?
They differ only in that:

- the `malloc()` can be called in user-space and kernel-space, and it allocates a physically fragmented memory area
- but `kmalloc()` can be called only in kernel-space, and it allocates physically contiguous memory chunk

or something else?

`kmalloc()` use pointer in virtual or physical addressing and what `kmalloc()` is different from `__ get_free_pages()`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `malloc()` you can call in kernel code is not the `malloc()` you call in user code, which is in the C standard library, which is not linked into the kernel. They share the same name, obviously, but that's about it...

Comment: What operating system are you using? I am interested in knowing where did you read about malloc in kernel space assuming that you are using linux As I never read about a malloc implementation in the kernel space in which I can use kmalloc/vmalloc depending on the requirements for the driver.... Moreover malloc in the userspace (glibc) is not even a primitive because calls dlmalloc() which calls mmap() or brk()..
After your post I tried to grep in the overall kernel and I could find malloc implementations only in "user level utils" and "user level drivers"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I answer to the second question, assuming that you are using Linux OS. Regarding to the first one please have a look to my comment.

`kmalloc`uses `get_free_page` to get the memory. The way in which the pages are collected depends on the second parameter ( `GFP_ATOMIC GFP_KERNEL ...` in which GFP means GET FREE PAGE). The advantage of kmalloc on the GFP is that it can fit multiple allocations into a single page.

some of the options for kmalloc are:

```
GFP_USER - Allocate memory on behalf of user. May sleep.
GFP_KERNEL - Allocate normal kernel ram. May sleep.
GFP_ATOMIC - Allocation will not sleep. May use emergency pools. For example, use this inside interrupt handlers.
GFP_HIGHUSER - Allocate pages from high memory.
GFP_NOIO - Do not do any I/O at all while trying to get memory.
GFP_NOFS - Do not make any fs calls while trying to get memory.
GFP_NOWAIT - Allocation will not sleep.
GFP_THISNODE - Allocate node-local memory only.
GFP_DMA - Allocation suitable for DMA. Should only be used for kmalloc caches. Otherwise, use a slab created with SLAB_DMA.
```

Apart from this `get_free_page` and `kmalloc` are very similar. `_get_free_pages` differs from `get_free_page` because it gives the pointer to the first byte of a memory area that is potentially ***several (physically contiguous) pages*** long.
Another function that is again very similar to   `get_free_page` is `get_zeroed_page(unsigned int flags)` which gets a single page like `get_free_page` but zeroes the memory

Comment: Thanks! i.e. `get_free_page()` get pointer which is always aligned to `PAGE_SIZE`, an oposite in `kmalloc()` get pointer which isn't aligned and may be on the same page as the other pointers, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

- malloc uses [Buddy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation) for allocation of chunks.
- The kmalloc kernel service, which allocates physically contiguous memory regions in the kernel address space, is in built on top of the slab and object cache interface which uses [slab allocator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation) algorithm.

[More details here](https://amitkumar25nov.wordpress.com/computer/memory/malloc-implementation/)